# sed replacing string with special characters

Tags: string, bash, shell, sed, replace

Surprisingly similar questions had been asked multiple times but none of the solutions worked for my use case - which is to replace a string which can contains all possible special characters.

In a text file, i.e

```
 hello.txt

 ABC="12'{}34[];|^)(*&^!^#~`!-567"
```

And a shell script

```
 run.sh

 #!/bin/sh
 key="12'{}34[];|^)(*&^!^#~`!-567"
 escappedKey=$(printf '%s\n' "$key" | sed -e 's/[]\/$*.^[]/\\&/g');

 value="345$`{}[]|%';"
 escappedValue=$(printf '%s\n' "$value" | sed -e 's/[]\/$*.^[]/\\&/g');

 sed -i "s/$escappedKey/$escappedValue/g" hello.txt
```

Expected result in

```
hello.txt

ABC="345$`{}[]|%';"
```

But the above sed cmd in run.sh doesn't work. And I have also tried with:

```
sed -e 's/[][\\^*+.$-]/\\\1/g'
```

from: [Replacing special characters in a shell script using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422367/replacing-special-characters-in-a-shell-script-using-sed)

```
sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g'
```

from: [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern)

but both doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following script should work for you:

```sh
key="12'{}34[];|^)(*&^!^#~\`!-567"
escappedKey=$(printf '%s\n' "$key" | sed 's/[]\/$*.^[]/\\&/g');

value="345$\`{}[]|%';"
escappedValue=$(printf '%s\n' "$value" | sed 's/[]\/$*.^[]/\\&/g');

sed "s/$escappedKey/$escappedValue/g" hello.txt
```

Note that you will need to escape tilde as `\'` in double quotes and also you are using `$key` to populate `escappedValue` by mistake.

**Output:**

```
ABC="345$`{}[]|%';"
```